# Simplicial formula for (co)homology cross product

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

I am looking to do some concrete computations of (co)homology cross products with some explicit simplicial complexes.  Let $K$ and $L$ be to finite abstract simplicial complexes.  I have seen the definition of the cross product for singular (co)homology and I have seen how if one chooses explicit Eilenberg-Zilber chain maps then one can get an explicit formula for the singular cross product.  I would like to know how to do this simplicially.

I know that there is a nice way to form a abstract simplicial complex $K \otimes L$ such that $| K \otimes L | \cong |K| \times |L|$.  I imagine that there are some nice simplicial Eilenberg-Zilber maps 
$$
S(K) \otimes S(L) \to S(K \otimes L) \\
S(K \otimes L) \to S(K) \otimes S(L)
$$
and if I new these this would give me the definition of the simplicial cross product in (co)hmology.

I am fairly new to things so I could be thinking of this all wrong.  Is this the correct idea to define a simplicial cross product and if so how can I cook up these explicit Eilenberg-Zilber maps?